# Inverse Kinematics in Java

Tags: inverse-kinematics, programming-languages

I'm planning to write an Inverse Kinematics controlled 6 dof virtual robot for Android. I did some research on packages avaliable and couldn't choose the right one which will satisfy my needs on this project. I've seen a work with Eigen in C++, and used it, it was just fine. But since i'm not so experienced in Java, i wanted to ask before i start, if someone knows some appropiate packages for these operations.

Here is what i found so far:

JAMA,
Vecmath,
Jmathtools,
EJML,
JAMPACK
I ask this because i really dont want to get stuck in the middle of my project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure this kind of question is suitable for this website. I'll leave it for others to decide though.

Comment: I understand your concern, sir. But what i ask is, to find the suitable one to compute inverse kinematics among these vector and linear algebra libraries. So, i do not ask anyone to promote or advertise anything, i just want to know if its there a specialized package for this particular task.

Comment: Are you looking for information on linear algebra packages for Java or IK packages for Java?

Comment: Hmm, these are what i found for now, but that would also be great if i could find an inverse kinematics library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are matrix-vector math libraries. They are related to inverse kinematics only because inverse kinematics involves matrices, vectors, and math. If you need an implementation of an inverse kinematics library, that is a different question. But any of those would be fine for doing the required math, once you solve the inverse kinematics in closed form or by some other method. Personally, I've used JAMA (it works).